# Method not found: class com.sun.el.stream.Stream.collect(null)

Tags: jsf, el

I am trying to use the java.util.stream.Stream class in a JSF application running on Payara Server 5 with JDK 11, but I keep getting a javax.el.MethodNotFoundException with the message "Method not found: class com.sun.el.stream.Stream.collect(null)".

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myList.stream().map(e -> e.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(', '))}"/>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything else I need to do to make this work?